# How to change the text color of suggestions in searchview?

Tags: android

I am using SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider for display recent suggestions in search view ,but the text color of suggestions is white ,I want to be black ,is there way to do that...any help please

```
import android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider;


public class MySuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.saleh.mysqlserver.helper.MySuggestionProvider";
public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES| DATABASE_MODE_2LINES;

public MySuggestionProvider() {
    setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
}


}

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search_friend, menu);
    this.menu=menu;
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    search.requestFocus();


    search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoCompleteTextView = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)
            search.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    autoCompleteTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    int count=search.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCount();
    Toast.makeText(this,""+count,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
        View mView= search.getSuggestionsAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }





    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions=new SearchRecentSuggestions(SearchFriendActivity.this
                    , MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY,
                    MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
            suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query,"");

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
           // loadHistory(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });





    return true;


}
```

Comment: show your code where are you displaying you data

Comment: public class MySuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.saleh.mysqlserver.helper.MySuggestionProvider";
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES| DATABASE_MODE_2LINES;

    public MySuggestionProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }


}

Comment: update your question and post all relevant code.